# Regarding Salesforce developer side

Tags: salesforce, custom-object

I'm a beginner in Salesforce and I'm trying to grasp the concept of Apex triggers. I understand that they are used to perform custom actions before or after records are inserted, updated, or deleted, but I'm struggling to understand how to write one. Could someone please provide a basic example of how to write a simple Apex trigger, explain its structure, and maybe walk me through how to deploy it in a Salesforce org?

I'm trying to create a custom object. I followed the steps outlined in the documentation, including navigating to Setup > Object Manager > Create > Custom Object. I expected to see a form where I could define the object's properties such as fields and relationships. However, when I clicked on 'Create,' I encountered an error message saying 'Insufficient Privileges.' I checked my user profile and made sure I have the necessary permissions for object creation, but the issue persists.

How to resolve this error and successfully create a custom object in Salesforce?